# Performance slowdown using a pointer to perform a reduction vs. using a normal variable

Tags: c, performance, gcc, x86, openmp

I need to perform an OpenMP reduction in C using a pointer variable (single element). As far as I know, the two alternatives to achieve this are:

```
double ptr* = ...
#pragma omp for reduction(max:ptr[0])
or
#pragma omp for reduction(max:ptr[:1])
```

However, performing the reduction into a pointer variable is significantly slower than using a normal variable.

Consider this example:

```
int REP = 1000000, ITER = 1000;

double red_var() {
    double foo = 0.0;

    #pragma omp parallel
    for (int i = 0; i < REP; ++i) {
        #pragma omp for reduction(+:foo)
        for (int j = 0; j < ITER; ++j) {
            foo += 1.0 / (j + 1);
        }
    }
    return foo;
}

double red_ptr() {
    double foos[1]; double *foo = foos;

    #pragma omp parallel
    for (int i = 0; i < REP; ++i) {
        #pragma omp for reduction(+:foo[0])
        for (int j = 0; j < ITER; ++j) {
            *foo += 1.0 / (j + 1);
        }
    }
    return *foo;
}
```

In my system, the first function (`red_var()`) is nearly 3x faster than the second function (`red_ptr()`).

My system:

- CPU: Intel Xeon Gold 5120
- OS: Ubuntu Server 22.04
- Compiler: GCC v11.3.0
- Compiler flags: -O3 -fopenmp

Analyzing the generated assembly code, I see that the compiler uses a `lock cmpxchg` instruction to perform the reduction in the first function. In contrast, it uses an OpenMP atomic region for the pointer reduction. Is there any way to tell the compiler it can also use a `lock cmpxchg` instruction when using a pointer?

#### Update

- `lock cmpxchg` is not executed in each iteration of the inner *for* loop. The compiler uses private accumulators and only performs the reduction into the shared variable at the end of the loop.
- Creating a `const restrict` pointer to tell the compiler that there is no aliasing and that the pointer is never updated does not change the generated assembly.
- Moving the reduction from the `omp for` to the `omp parallel` improves the performance, but only because the reduction is performed only once. The compiler still creates an atomic region for the pointer reduction.
- Compiling the example in C++ and substituting the pointer with a reference does fix the issue. The generated assembly for the reference version uses `lock cmpxchg`.
- Compiling with `-ffast-math` or `-march=native` does not seem to improve the generated assembly or the performance.
- Clang (v14.0.0) and ICX (v2023.1.0) compilers use `lock cmpxchg` in the two reductions. The binaries generated by these compilers show similar execution times for both functions.

Comment: `lock cmpxchg` every iteration is still horrible; you want it to use per-thread accumulators and reduce across threads outside the loops, just once at the end.  In fact multiple accumulators across multiple SIMD vectors.  Like maybe `#pragma omp simd reduction` instead of just `omp reduction` if I'm remembering at all correctly.

Comment: @PeterCordes in the first version the lock is probably not in the explicit loop, but in a hidden loop that sums the hidden accumulators.

Comment: Maybe that in the pointer version, the compiler assumes that `foo` may change during execution (even if it doesn't), while in the variable version he knows that `&foo` won't change. Hence the different behavior.

Comment: What if you put the reduction not in the `omp for` pragma but in the `omp parallel` pragma?

Comment: @PierU Have a small summation loop is way better than doing every reduction step atomically/critically. But I'm kinda surprised at this behavior. I once coded a `declare reduction` that printed out its inputs/output and I concluded that OMP used a tree for the reduction. Of course the compiler may be at liberty to use other strategies for cases it can optimize. OP: can you try a different compiler? And make sure your optimizaiton levels are set high enough? Turn off anything like `fp-model=precise`.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout: GCC's default is `-fno-fast-math`, so yeah might be interesting to try `-O3 -ffast-math`, and maybe `-march=native`.   ICC is the opposite of other mainstream compilers, where the default is `fp-model=fast=1` or something, although not as aggressive as `fast=2`.

Comment: Seems you've found a GCC missed optimization.  You could report it on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

Comment: Note that GCC generate an inefficient inner loop : it is neither unrolled nor vectorized. Clang does that. Thus, this is not the only missed optimization in this basic harmonic number computation. One possible reasons why GCC does not perform the pointer optimization is that it splits the OpenMP code into two functions so to simplify some computation at the expense of possibly missed optimizations like this.

Comment: Bug reported in [gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=110319)